# Unable to Connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

My system OS is windows7 ultimate x64 and I installed visual studio 2012 on it. Newly I get an error as bellow when I want to debug any program on my system:
[image]

I search for this error every where [msdn,stackoverflow,...] but I don't get my answer and  I've still this error, so can't debug my programs. Then I had to install visual studio on VmWare with windows 7 x64, just as like my system OS - so it's worked and I can debug on virtual system. But I don't like this, because virtual machine takes a lot of disk capacity.

I think my originally problem is knowledge about remote debugging. because It's a question for me that, why I need debug a local or native program with remote debugging when I don't use an external system ?

**To solution of my problem, I try these :**
1. Check my windows firewall and turned it off.
2. Check my internet proxy to it's default and make sure don't use any proxy when I use VS 2012.
3. Even I checked msvsmon.exe x64 is running.
[image]
4. I checked Visual Studio runs as administrator.

Sooooo, everyone can help me with this,please?